# LINQ query to get outstanding invoices

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In my Entity Framework application, I have an Entity called `Invoice.cs`, here is what that looks like:

```
public class Invoice : IEntity
{
  public Invoice()
  {
    Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
    CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
  }

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public decimal Amount { get; set; }
  public decimal Discount { get; set; }
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
  public bool IsSaleOrderInvoice { get; set; }
  public InvoiceStatus Status { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
  public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
  public int OrderId { get; set; }
  public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}

public enum InvoiceStatus
{
  Outstanding = 0,
  Settled = 1,
  Overpaid = 2
}
```

I am attempting to query the database to get a list of all outstanding invoices. An outstanding invoice is the following:

> If the **total of the payments** made against the Invoice are **less than the Invoice Amount**, then the invoice is *Outstanding*.

I'm stuck on working out if an invoice is outstanding or not in my LINQ query, which currently looks like this:

```
var outstandingInvoices = from inv in _context.Invoices
    where !inv.IsDeleted && inv.Date >= startDate && inv.Date <= endDate
    select inv;
```

`startDate` and `endDate` are parameters passed in to filter the result.

Comment: + let total = inv.Payments.SUM(o=>o.someamount)
before where clause
so you can check with inv.Amount <> total

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `Payment` entity has an `Amount` property (otherwise you should change it to appropriate property name):

```
var outstandingInvoices = from inv in _context.Invoices
                          where inv.Payments.Sum(p => p.Amount) < inv.Amount
                          select inv;
```

You optionally can add filters which you have now for deleted status and dates of invoice, but from definition of *outstanding* invoice, this is how you should check whether invoice is outstanding.

Generated query will look like:

```
SELECT
    result.Id,
    result.Amount,
    result.Discount,
    result.IsDeleted,
    -- etc
    FROM (SELECT
            i.Id,
            i.Amount,
            i.Discount,
            i.IsDeleted,
            -- etc
            (SELECT SUM(p.Amount) 
             FROM [dbo].[Payments] p 
             WHERE i.Id = p.Invoice_Id) AS totalPayment
          FROM [dbo].[Invoices] AS i
    )  AS result
    WHERE totalPayment < result.Amount
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be added as a condition to remaining given by the OP, not the only condition

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I have pointed that other filter can be added, but question states that *'I am attempting to query the database to get a list of **all** outstanding invoices'* - that's why I provided query for getting all outstanding invoices with note about adding additional filters

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy there was another "gotcha" that has just come to light. Please have a read of the updated Q.

Comment: @Ciwan there was no information about currencies in original question, so please create new question instead of changing question and invalidating all answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just use **`Payments.Sum()`**

```
var result = from inv in _context.Invoices
                          where inv.Payments.Sum(payment => payment.Amount) < inv.Amount
                          select inv;
```

Comment: Payments is not a decimal type you are comparing with `Amount`

Comment: Shouldn't this be added as a condition to remaining given by the OP, not the only condition

Answer (score 1):

```
var outstandingInvoices = from inv in _context.Invoices
where !inv.IsDeleted && inv.Date >= startDate && inv.Date <= endDate
      && inv.Payments.Count() < inv.Amount
select inv;
```

Add `inv.Payments.Count() < inv.Amount` to your where clause

Or if you have an `amount` in your class and you need to sum them up, use `inv.Payments.sum(p=>p.TheAmountProperty) < inv.Amount`

Comment: Why `Count`, why not `Sum`